# Subset (list of lists) nested Lists

Tags: r, list, subset

I am trying to subset thead/tbody without directly calling rowlist$td$list$item$table$thead or rowlist[[td]][[list]][[item]][[table]][[thead]]. This
`unlist(rowlist, use.names=FALSE )[ grepl( "tbody", names(unlist(rowlist)))]`  serves my purpose except I need it as multiple rows (e.g. two tr's in tbody)(i can split it but seems counter intuitive .
I know there should be a better way to work with HTML/XML but this is got I got for now.

```
str(rowlist)
List of 1
 $ td:List of 1
  ..$ list:List of 1
  .. ..$ item:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ table:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ thead:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ tr:List of 7
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Test"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Outcome"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Subset"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Cups"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Bowls"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Plates"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ th:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Jars"
  .. .. .. ..$ tbody:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ tr:List of 7
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "test1"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "High"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Low"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Gold"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Blue"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Green"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "red"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "id_511"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ tr:List of 7
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "test2"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Low"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "High"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Pink"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Blue"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td:List of 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Purple"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ td: list()
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "id_512"
  .. ..- attr(*, "styleCode")= chr "none"
```

List looks like this

```
rowlist<-list(td = structure(list(list = structure(list(item = list(table = list(
  thead = list(tr = list(
    th = list("Test"), th = list("Outcome"), th = list("Set"), th = list("Cups"), th = list("Bowls"), th = list( "Plates"), th = list("Jars"))), 
  tbody = list(tr = structure(
    list(td = list("test1"), td = list("High"), td = list("Low"), td = list("Gold"), td = list("Blue"), td = list("Green"), td = list("Red")), ID = "id_511"), 
    tr = structure(
      list(td = list("test2"), td = list("Low"), td = list("High"), td = list("Pink"), td = list("Blue"), td = list("Purple"), td = list()), ID = "id_512"))))), styleCode = "none")), colspan = "20"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Use ` dput()` rather than `str()` so we can copy/paste the data into R. Also, what was this data before a list? Was it an html document? Using an html parser would probably make it easier to navigate and subset the data rather than working with nested lists.

Comment: It's a HTML table within a XML doc, xml2 as_list has allowed me easier access to some data through loops e.g. instead of test/some/other/thing I can do test[[3]][[2]][[4]]

Comment: When an `xml2` you can easily select nodes with xpath expressions. It's a bit messier with lists of lists. Can you share the HTML/XML data instead?

Comment: the node selection has become an issue since some nodes have the same name and both similar different content which gets badly mixed up, it is not a regular XML doc skirting on the edge or xml rules, the list does make mapping it much more simple for me. The xml is to huge to obfuscate to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object has to be handled as  a nested list, one approach is to use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extension of base `rapply`):

```r
library(rrapply)  ## v1.2.1

out <- rrapply(rowlist, 
        classes = "list",
        condition = function(x, .xname) .xname %in% c("thead", "tbody"), 
        how = "flatten")

str(out, list.len = 2)
#> List of 2
#>  $ thead:List of 1
#>   ..$ tr:List of 7
#>   .. ..$ th:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "Test"
#>   .. ..$ th:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "Outcome"
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]
#>  $ tbody:List of 2
#>   ..$ tr:List of 7
#>   .. ..$ td:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "test1"
#>   .. ..$ td:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "High"
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "id_511"
#>   ..$ tr:List of 7
#>   .. ..$ td:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "test2"
#>   .. ..$ td:List of 1
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr "Low"
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "ID")= chr "id_512"
```

Here, the `condition` function returns only nodes with names `thead` or `tbody`, `how = "flatten"` returns the nodes in a flat list (`how = "prune"` would prune the nodes keeping the original list structure), and `classes = "list"` does not skip intermediate list nodes (as would be the case with base `rapply()`).